React, SocketIO - Handling fetch request whilst receving real time data
When the user navigates to /chats, I fetch the users most recent chats. (When app mounts on / route, the chat list is not fetched):
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchChatList = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await axiosPrivate.get(`${BASE_URL}/api/chats/`)
            dispatch(setChats({ chats: response.data }))
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    }

    fetchChatList()
}, [axiosPrivate, dispatch])

I have a global listener, which uses socketio to receive and handle new chats in real time. My issue is what if I receive realtime chats whilst fetching the chats at the same time?
The problem is that the fetched chats would override the newly received chat. This is because setChats reducer simply sets the chats array equal to the data it is passed. There is also no guarantee that the new chat/chats received in realtime will be included in the fetch result.
One potential solution is to temporarily store realtime chats when the chat list hasn't been fetched yet, and then merge the results, however this would include ensuring that the fetched chat list doesn't include the newly received chats as this would be a duplication issue. This isn't a good solution in my opinion. Is there any other potential strategies to overcome this issue?

Expanding on the original question, you may ask what to do if the last received data is outdated.
IMO, the data you operate with should have some lastUpdated field with a timestamp set on the backend side.
Then, on the client, you would probably still want to merge the fetched results with real-time results resolving the duplicates with the freshest data according to the lastUpdated timestamp.
